# ¿Es buena práctica enviar parámetros por medio queryString?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

mi consulta es la siguiente:

Tengo un proyecto en Asp net mvc 5 el cual necesito enviarle parámetros al controlador y lo estoy haciendo por medio de javascript, funciona perfectamente, pero cuando modifico los valores de mi url consulta nuevamente a la base de datos y obtengo el nueva data, ya que eso no debería pasar.

Código :

```
location.href = location.origin + '/Area/Controller/Registro?id=' + id + '&tipo=' + tipo;
```

PD: Acepto cualquier recomendación. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buena o mala practica depende de lo que quieras hacer.

Si lo que requieres es guardar información(Crear o Actualizar), deberías pensar en usar el método POST, este envía oculta la información y el cliente no podrá verla (No se mostrara en la URL)
El método GET expone la información en la URL, lo mas usual es que se use para hacer una paginacion o por cuestiones de SEO, dependera del proyecto que estes realizando.

Puedes checar https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods para que te des una idea mejor de todos los métodos de petecion del protocolo HTTP, estos son independientes de la tecnología que uses(PHP,ASP.NET, JAVA, etc), se comportan de la misma manera.

Por cierto, nunca expongas los id de alguna tabla en la URL ya que esto puede prestarse a que las personas puedan darse una idea de como puede estar estructurada tu BD y puedan causarte daño a la misma, bueno dependiendo de como este validada la información en el backend.

Comment: Nunca exponer los Ids también es relativo, hay Ids que no requieren ser protegidos ni tampoco hay problema en ser adivinados, por ejemplo: Ids correlativos de una tabla de solo consulta.